# Windows 7 NODE_PATH global var set but not recognized in package.json

Tags: node.js, windows-7, path, package, global-variables

I installed node v6.0.0, npm v3.8.6 on windows 7 x86. Defined global variable NODE_PATH:

```
C:\Users\usr\dev\test>echo %NODE_PATH%
%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

Downloaded diferent projects to start developing but always get same error:

```
'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Tried with different package scripts but always same error:

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "NODE_PATH=. browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] src/client/index.js > public/app.js",

"serve": "NODE_PATH=./dist node dist/src/server",
```

}

How to get NODE_PATH recognized as a global variable?

Comment: You can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38608811/1933051) I gave lately on another similar question. I think it might help you here too. At least it did work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `scripts` definition in `package.json` which links to a file:

```
"scripts" : { "start" : "node server.js" }
```

which contains the `process.env.NODE_PATH` reference:

```
process.env.NODE_PATH
```

**REFERENCES**

- [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)
- [process API: process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)